# Slow LAN connection on one machine but not another

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, lan

I am using the same ethernet cable on two different machines and getting two incredibly different results.  The following tests were done on a Windows 7 desktop and a Linux laptop.

On my laptop, SpeedTest.net shows `49ms ping` and `13.5 mb/s down`.

On my desktop, I can not load `SpeedTest.net` and I can barely load `google.com`.

**Edit:** For whatever reason the internet is slightly faster now, I was able to run a speed test and got `.98 mb/s down`

Both computers were working exactly as expected yesterday.  However, today I moved to a new residence.  So I'm wondering if the desktop is getting hung up on old configs or maybe if it was damaged during the move (I checked the MoBo for any visible signs of damange, there were none).  I don't have any proprietary network software installed.

I have a second partition dedicated to a Linux install (on my desktop).  I booted my computer into Linux and it won't even detect that I have a LAN cable connected (Kernel 3.10 Manjaro).  On Linux my ethernet port doesn't even blink its light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actaully, as it turns out, my networking card on my MoBo was failing.  I picked up a USB to Ethernet dongle from Best Buy and my internet works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though there might be a problem with the network card on your desktop and not the cable or modem.

If the ethernet cable as you mention works on the laptop just fine then the problem is in your network card or drivers. See if you can update the drivers for the card.

Also make sure the cable is securely in the NIC. Sometimes it can be in there but loose so the contact between the card and cable is not consistent.

Comment: Windows says the best driver is installed.  I've tried two different ethernet cables and I'm certain both were secure.

Comment: Do you have static IP/Gateway settings on the LAN? That can sometimes cause the issue.

Comment: I ended up following the instructions here and it worked: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx